# how to pass dropdown dynamic value in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a dropdown list the value of each item generate dynamic

```
          <?php
  include('../db_inc.php');
$sql="select * from genre";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    $option =$row->genre_name;
    $value =$row->genre_id;
    echo '<option value='.$value.'>'.$option.'</option>';

    }
?>
```

i want pass selected item value from dropdown to server and save that to database,
i can do that with ajax,but i want to know php can do that without ajax function?

Comment: PHP cannot do it alone, unless you reload the whole page. That's what AJAX is for.  PHP has no connection to the client browser, really.

Comment: In other words, if you just submit the form as normal (assuming this is in a proper `<form>` tag) and PHP will get the value in `$_POST`.

Comment: if i add dropdown in `<form>` how can access the value of selected dropdown item on server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send it with a `<form>` tag and submit form with on dropdown **onchange** attribute. then get it with **php** and save that to database.

```
<form name='form1' method='post' action=''>
    <?php
      include('../db_inc.php');
    $sql="select * from genre";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    echo '<select onchange="form1.submit();">';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
        $option =$row->genre_name;
        $value =$row->genre_id;
        echo '<option value='.$value.'>'.$option.'</option>';

        }
    echo '</select>';
    ?>
</form>
```

Comment: ok, if i use onchange() method,how can i access the value on server?

Answer (score 1):

PHP runs on server side. Dropdown list on client side. You need somehow send the value from client to server (post, get, ajax, websocket, etc).
The answer is NO.

Comment: i mean how can perform that with post?

Comment: Use mehdi's sample. Add to select property name.
<select name="blabla" ...>
At server side $selected=$_POST["blabla"]